# How can i retrieve the core media formats other than using the key_mime?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I know of a way and that's by calling `String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);` but i am currently trying to dig deeper, such as this [core media formats list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZrAI.png). You can see there's many different type of AAC, AAC LC, HE-AACv1 (AAC+), HE-AACv2 (enhanced AAC+) and such. KEY_MIME will not return you these values. Is there any way to retrieve from the Mediaformat the core media formats?

Comment: what are you trying exactly to do ?To see what codecs are in a video , or ?

Comment: hmm, to retrieve the information in media files, both video and audio. In those files lies a header where information are in, what i am trying to do is retrieve all the information i need. Above i did assign the file's mime type into a string var mime, but i need something more detailed, like the mime type are of .aac extensions, what acc is it, AAC LC? HE-AACv1(AAC+)? or HE-AACv2(enhanced AAC+)? MediaFormat.KEY_MIME doesn't return such detailed info. Click on the link you would see the core media formats that i wish to retrieve.

Comment: When i need to do smth like this I use the android ffmpeg warper (google for ) and I get all I need

Answer (score 0):

yeah but the thing is i can't use libraries such as ffmpeg wrappers. i found another class that returns me the more detailed formate, **MediaMetadataRetriever**.

And this is the method example:
//target the file

```
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(filepath);
```

//then call method

`mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE);`

found what i need and hope you guys may find this useful too.